# Pass statement if previous magnet URL is the same

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple script in python 2.7 that receives multiple data sets every second over UDP. Then places each of these data sets into individual magnet URLs and opens them.

Many times, a data set can be the same as the previous one(s), and therefore I don't want to open the same magnet URL multiple times.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
while True:
    var = s.recv(30)

    url = "magnet://myhost.com/{0}".format(var)

    os.startfile(url)
```

As an example, I can receive the following data sets:

```
a
a
a
b
b
a
a
e
e
e
```

Essentially, if two data sets are the same, then the same magnet URLs are produced. In the example above, I would like it to open the first magnet URL (a), but skip (pass) the next two a's. Then open the first b URL but skip the next b. If data set a is sent again, then open the first one but skip the following a's. So on and so forth.

I'm guessing that I could use an if/else and a pass statement for this, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you only need to skip a value if it is the same of the previous one, just use a simple variable to keep trace of it :

```
old = None
while True:
    var = s.recv(30)
    if var != old:
        old = var
        url = "magnet://myhost.com/{0}".format(var)
        os.startfile(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `set` of previously seen items:

```
seen = set()
while True:
    var = s.recv(30)
    if var not in seen:
        url = "magnet://myhost.com/{0}".format(var)
        os.startfile(url)
        seen.add(var)
```

Comment: This seems to work. However, If I get a data set of "a", then "b" and then "a" again, then that second "a" doesn't work because it is already seen.

Comment: Oh, then I misread your question, and @figs' answer was actually correct and should be undeleted.